# Ionic 2 - How to get back the root nav page of selected tab while switching tabs

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have used ion-tabs in my ionic app. Here I can not get the root page which I set for the tabs at the first click.

**My code changes are,**

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="mySelectedIndex" color="footerbar" class="bottomenu">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="ios-home" [root]="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="ios-albums" (ionSelect)="showOrHideTabs()" 
        [root]="store"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="ios-person" [root]="user"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="ios-settings" [root]="settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And the components is,

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public app: App) {
        this.mySelectedIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
        this.home = 'HomePage';
        this.store = 'StoreTabsPage';
        this.user = 'MyInfoViewPage';
        this.settings = 'SettingsPage';
    }
```

I have following pages

1. Home Page

   - Program create page
2. Store Info page
3. My info page
4. Settings page

Say, I am going to navigate the page to program create (sub page) from home page (ion-tab)
then I am switching the tab to store info page (ion-tab).
At this time, If I come back to home page means, The program create page alone shown and the home page is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic lifecycle hooks to `pop()` the page.

You can just do something like this in your `program-create.ts`

```
ionViewWillLeave(){
 this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

I would suggest you to use a `ModalController` to push the `ProgramCreatePage` than using `navCtrl`

Comment: Why don't you try using Modals ?

Comment: Could you please share some examples?

Comment: Hi ,
Used Modals to navigating new pages. Works like a charm.
Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.navCtrl.popToRoot() function on every subpage in ionViewWillLeave(). You can find more about it here. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Hi,
We can not set popToRoot() for all sub pages, the nav stock will be destroyed for every child pages. We can use modals to avoid these kind of issues.